Quantize and fine-tune Llama 3.1 8B for Ollama
I want to fine-tune locally the Meta's Llama 3.1 8B Instruct model with custom data and then save it in a format compatible with Ollama for further inference. As I do everything locally and don't have unlimited resources (24 GB VRAM), I need to quantize the model with the requirement that the safetensors should be in either in F16, F32 or BF16 dtype otherwise Ollama cannot parse them.
I implemented the following code to fetch the base model from HF hub and fine tune it:
def get_model_and_tokenizer(model_id: str) -> Tuple[LlamaForCausalLM, PreTrainedTokenizerFast]:
    """
    Args:
        model_id: The model id to load from the Hugging Face model hub
    Returns:
        A tuple containing the model and tokenizer
    """
    tokenizer: PreTrainedTokenizerFast = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
    tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token

    bnb_config: BitsAndBytesConfig = BitsAndBytesConfig(
        load_in_4bit=True,
        bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
        bnb_4bit_compute_dtype="float16",
        bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=True,
        bnb_4bit_quant_storage="float16"
    )

    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        model_id,
        quantization_config=bnb_config,
        device_map="auto"
    )

    model.config.use_cache = False
    model.config.pretraining_tp = 1

    return model, tokenizer


def fine_tune(model: LlamaForCausalLM, tokenizer: PreTrainedTokenizerFast) -> None:
    train_dataset, validation_dataset = prepare_dataset(
        path="data/all.jsonl",
        test_ratio=0.1
    )

    peft_config: LoraConfig = LoraConfig(
        r=8,
        lora_alpha=16,
        lora_dropout=0.05,
        bias="none",
        task_type="CAUSAL_LM",
    )

    training_arguments: TrainingArguments = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir=OUTPUT_MODEL_NAME,
        overwrite_output_dir=True,
        per_device_train_batch_size=4,
        gradient_accumulation_steps=16,
        optim="paged_adamw_32bit",
        learning_rate=5e-5,
        lr_scheduler_type="cosine",
        save_strategy="epoch",
        logging_steps=10,
        num_train_epochs=EPOCHS,
        max_steps=250,
        fp16=True
    )

    sft_config: SFTConfig = SFTConfig(**training_arguments.to_dict())

    trainer: SFTTrainer = SFTTrainer(
        model=model,
        train_dataset=train_dataset,
        eval_dataset=validation_dataset,
        peft_config=peft_config,
        dataset_text_field="text",
        args=sft_config,
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
        max_seq_length=1024
    )

    trainer.train()

    # Merge the fine-tuned model with the base model
    merged_model = trainer.model.merge_and_unload()

    # Save the merged model
    merged_model.save_pretrained(f'output_models/{OUTPUT_MODEL_NAME}')
    tokenizer.save_pretrained(f'output_models/{OUTPUT_MODEL_NAME}')

Among the things I tried are:

Converting the model to GGUF format with llama.cpp but it crashes with the error Can not map tensor 'model.layers.0.mlp.down_proj.weight.absmax';
Different values for bnb_4bit_quant_storage but it always saved the model with U8 tensors;
Removing the BitsAndBytes config and just put a load_in_8bits=True (Same with 4bits) in the from_pretrained() call, but then I have OOM errors on the GPU;
Manually reformat the tensors before merging or before saving the model with the code below:

for param in trainer.model.parameters():
    if param.dtype == torch.uint8 or param.dtype == torch.int8:
        param.data = param.data.to(torch.float16)

It seems Ollama doesn't handle BitsAndBytes quantization according to their maintainers. However I'm curious about how that could matter if the tensors are saved with the correct F16/F32/BF16 dtype.
So apart from BitsAndBytes, do you recommend any other standard framework that could work with Ollama requirements ?

My solution is to use unsloth instead of standard hugging face as it supports export in GGUF directly with different quantization options that have the proper format for Ollama. Also better performances (twice as fast and 60% less memory on my hardware).
